# How to integrate a core php page with a codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an existing core(raw) php form, which has its own css, js and image files. Now I have made a codeigniter project and I have made a link in one of its view pages, which would direct it to the core php form, which I have.
How should I integrate this single core php folder with my codeigniter project.

Below is the link which should take me to the form:

```
 <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url('BluemasonsForm/index'); ?>">
```

Comment: Create a function in home controller for this page....

Comment: Just a tip when you need to go do the index controller function you dont need to call it in url `<?php echo base_url('bluemasonsform/'); ?>` Also on the files and class names only the first letter should be upper case

Comment: creating a home controller is not working

Comment: be specific with problem

Comment: `<?= base_url('bluemasonsform/'); ?>`

Answer (score -2):

You can make the core project as your subdomain and link to with your codeigniter project.